# On which entities do any user have read access when access is given to crm org?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, entities, powerapps-modeldriven

I wanted to know on which entities does an user have by default a read access initially when no security role is assigned to the user?
I wanted to know because any user who do not have any security role can still access case & accounts entity through advanced find! Is this expected behavior? If yes then is this documented any where?

Comment: Does that user have any Team membership and Team has security role?

Answer (score 0):

All users must be assigned to at least one security role in order to have access to Dynamics 365. The security roles can be assigned to the user directly or to the access team he belongs to.

Can you double-check the security roles assigned to the user and verify team's security roles ?

Answer (score 0):

The user has to have a security role assigned to get into CRM. Check existing teams to see if the user is a member of and also he/she will have access to the records shared to him/her. Which entities user can access to are based on the roles/team he/she has been assigned. Check role/team setting for details.